Does scalar field dark matter behave like dust in cosmology?
A uniform scalar field has pressure equal to its energy density (equation of state $w=1$) and so dilutes very rapidly as the universe expands, $\rho \approx a^{-6}$. However, some theories of dark matter use scalar particles (e.g., light axion-like particles for fuzzy dark matter), and dark matter dilutes like normal matter, $\rho \approx a^{-3}$ in the $\Lambda$-CDM model.
Do scalar particles therefore behave like normal matter (pressureless, e.o.s. $w=0$) once they have clumped into galaxies and are no longer behaving as a uniform classical field?

It has nothing to do with spatial variation; it just depends on the interplay between the field's kinetic ($\dot{\phi}^2/2$) and potential energy ($V(\phi)$) densities. If the field has only potential energy but a static value, $w = -1$. If the field has no potential but a varying value, $w = 1$ as you said. If $V(\phi)$ is harmonic and energy oscillates between kinetic and potential, then $w = 0$, and that's what's relevant for scalar field DM models.

@knzhou I think that comment could be posted as an answer.

Note, just for a little extra information, for any theory of dark matter to be consistent with observations, the density should be $\rho\propto a^{-3}$. If it is a different power of $a^{-n}$, then it won't produce enough dark matter via, for example, the \textit{misalignment mechanism}. A theory that fails this test is massive spin-1 matter.

Thanks to @knzhou for clearing up my confusion in their comment. I'm not sure where I got the idea that $p=\rho$ for a scalar field, but this is not always the case. Looking at the energy density and pressure of a scalar field, we have (roughly speaking):
$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2+V(\phi)$$
$$p=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2-V(\phi)$$
As knzhou indicated, in the cosmological context we can just ignore spatial variation, and then if the kinetic energy of the field dominates, we get $p\approx\rho$, while if the potential energy dominates, we get $p\approx -\rho$. If the kinetic and potential energies balance out (as is the case on average for a free field with $V(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$) then $p\approx 0$.
